# Coupling torsion to electromagnetism and torsion tensor decomposition

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, differential-geometry

When extending general relativity to include electromagnetism, several authors (e.g. Novello, Sabbata ecc.) assume that the traceless part of the torsion tensor vanishes or is deliberately set to zero. Then, either the trace or axial part of the torsion is used in association with the electromagnetic potential (coupling). Is there any reason why, besides mathematical convenience, the leftover part of the torsion is set to zero?
Is it related to gauge invariance, as [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27356/torsion-and-gauge-invariant-em-kinetic-term) and the answer there seem to imply?

Furthermore, is it correct to consider the decomposition of the torsion tensor into three components - i.e., trace part, axial part, and traceless part - as the most general one?
The decomposition I'm referring to is the following:

$$  
T^\lambda_{\phantom{\mu}\mu\nu} = \bar{T}^\lambda_{\phantom{\mu}\mu\nu} + \frac{1}{6}\epsilon_{\lambda\mu\nu\rho}V^\rho + \frac{1}{3}(g_{\lambda\nu}T_\mu - g_{\lambda\mu}T_\nu)
$$

where $\bar{T}^\lambda_{\mu\nu}$ is the traceless part of torsion, $V^\rho$ is the axial torsion vector or "pseudo-trace" and $T_\mu$ is the torsion trace vector.
This is found for example in [Sur and Bhatia](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0394v2) (Appendix, A-7 to A-10) and in the answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/381557/decomposition-of-the-torsion-tensor), although perhaps with a different formalism.

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer? Does the question need clarification?